# Get from api in useEffect and render components accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Im having troubles rendering components based on api calls in React. I fetch my data in useEffect hook update a state with the data. The state is null for a while before the api get all the data but by that time, the components are rendering with null values. This is what I have:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Poll = (props) => {

const [poll, setPoll] = useState(null);
//if found is 0 not loaded, 1 is found, 2 is not found err
const [found, setFound] = useState(0);


useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`api/poll/${props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            setPoll(res.data);
            setFound(1);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
            setFound(2);
        });
}, [])


if(found===2) {
    return(
        <Redirect to="/" push />
    )
}else{
    console.log(poll)
    return (
        <div>


        </div>
    )
}

}

export default Poll
```

That is my workaround but it doesnt feel like thats the way it should be done. How can I set it so that I wait for my api data to get back then render components accordingly?

Comment: It's a default behavior of react. At initial phase it renders with initial state null. You may show some loading icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to track the state of the API call like `const [found, setFound] = useState(1)`. Just check if poll exists and also you can create a new state variable for tracking the error.

For example `if (!poll) { return <div>Loading...</div>}` this will render a div with 'loading...' when there is no data. See the code below, for complete solution,

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Poll = (props) => {

   const [poll, setPoll] = useState(null);

   const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);


   useEffect(() => {
     axios.get(`api/poll/${props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            setPoll(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
            setHasError(true)
        });
  }, [])


  if(!poll) {
    console.log('data is still loading')
    return(
       <div>Loading....</div>
    )
   }

  if (hasError) {
   console.log('error when fetching data');

   return (
     <Redirect to="/" push />
   )
 }


 return (
   <div>
    {
      poll && <div>/* The JSX you want to display for the poll*/</div>
    }
   </div>
 );
}

export default Poll
```

Comment: This works except for the error. In the catch block the console prints the error but when it checks the state to redirect, that if statement doesnt run

Comment: Does it not redirect to path `/` ? Try returning some jsx from the same block like `if (error) { return (<div>{error.message}</div> }` and see if you can see the rendered element, if that's the case something is going wrong with the redirect.

Comment: It doesnt even console log the error in that if statement. I dont think its the redirect

Comment: I have updated the answer, have a look at how the error is handled.

Comment: Now error state is toggled by a simple boolean value if it doesn't work then something else completely different is wrong.

Comment: It still doesnt work I think i know why, when there is an error then poll still doesnt have a value so it stays in that if statement. Any workarounds to that? Im going to try to check for error in the !poll

Comment: Yes it works by doing what I just commented thank you for the help!

Comment: This will fail if `res.data` is null, it will stay in the loading screen forever, that's why a loading variable is needed, that's how most libraries handle their status, like apollo https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/ for example

Comment: Here the API call is to a rest endpoint, where the response is structured and not null if it a successful API call, if it fails the promise will be rejected with an error.

Comment: The response object can’t be null but their properties can, in this case `data`.

Comment: Please have a look at how axios works @ludwiguer [github repo](https://github.com/axios/axios). `res.data` is not a property which the API returns it the actual response body itself, the response `res` object has other information as properties like `headers`, `status`, `statusText`, etc.

Comment: Maybe you should be the one checking the docs, data can be null in axios ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

In your than, try to use a filter:

`setPoll(poll.filter(poll => poll.id !== id));`

Make sure to replace id by your identificator

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to have other variables for the loading and error states like this

```
const Poll = (props) => {

    const [poll, setPoll] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios.get(`api/poll/${props.match.params.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                setPoll(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message);
                setError(true);
            })
            .finally(()=> {
                setLoading(false);
            };
    }, [])


    if(error) return <span>error<span/>
    if(loading) return <span>loading<span/>
    return (
        <div>
           // your poll data

        </div>
    )
}
```